# Okio's BufferedSource request() only fires once

Tags: retrofit2, okio

I'm downloading a file using a Retrofit2 implementation of a REST API, per the nice tutorial at https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-download-files-from-server.

My API interface declares the `@GET` as `@Streaming`, and indeed when I read from the `InputStream` given me by `byteStream()`, I can read the entire 29 MB file.

What I'd like to do is read it all in 4 MB chunks, so I'm using Okio's handy `BufferedSource`. The problem is that my call to `request(4*1024*1024)` returns `true` only *once*, though the total file size is something on the order of 29 MB.

My Java:

```
      @Streaming @GET Call<ResponseBody> get(@Url String url);

      // ...

      Response<ResponseBody> response = api.get("https://my.file.url");

      final int bufSize = 4*1024*1024;
      byte[] buffer;
      long total;

      InputStream is = response.body().byteStream();
      BufferedSource ss = Okio.buffer(Okio.source(is));
      // Is this the same as ss=response.body().source() ??

      while (ss.request(bufSize)) {
         buffer = ss.readByteArray();
         total += doSomethingUsefulWith(buffer);
         System.out.println("Running total: " + total);
      }

      // Capture the < 4MB residue
      buffer = ss.readByteArray();

      if (buffer.length > 0) {
         total += doSomethingUsefulWith(buffer);
         System.out.println("Total: " + total);
      }

      System.out.println("That's all, folks!");
```

Console output:

```
Running total: 4194304
That's all, folks!
```

Again, the raw `InputStream` does give me the full 29 MB, I've done it before. Do I misunderstand `request()`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, simplify to `ss=response.body().source()`

Comment: also, note that `request` will return false at the end, so you'll miss the last 5MB (29-(8+8+8)). not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `ss.readByteArray()` will read the entire body into a byte array. Did you mean to do `ss.readByteArray(bufSize)`?

Comment: Thanks -- I think you may be right here and in your comments. I have since moved on to another solution but I may revisit this later. (Also, I did then have code to handle the last few MB, but good catch.)